# How do I turn off automatic updates in Aptana Studio for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, updates

I installed Aptana Studio plugins for Eclipse and now Eclipse startup is slower than ever because Aptana Studio always checks for updates at startup -- and it's really slow!

How do I turn off auto updates in Aptana?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Window->Preferences, find the Install/Update item in the tree and locate Automatic Updates.  You can change the update behavior here.

Comment: thanks. i would vote u up but don't have enuf reputation... :-(

Comment: This may work for the Eclipse platform but it doesn't seem to work for the update checking of eclipse plugins.  Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For Aptana updates go to Window->Preferences.  Then open the Aptana->Install/Update->Automatic_Updates preference panel.  Once there deselect the "Automatically find new updates and notify me" check box.

Comment: This may work for the Eclipse platform but it doesn't seem to work for the update checking of eclipse plugins.  Any idea how to do that?